# No module named '_plotly_utils'

Tags: python, plotly

I use windows system with pyCharm. I tried to use plot in my code so I add "import plotly" at the beginning, and I install plotly package in the project interpreter (plotly version is the latest, 3.7.0). 
When I tried to run my program, it has a ModuleNotFoundError, stating no module named '_plotly_utils'

I'm confused and I don't know what else package should I install or if there's anything else I can do to solve this problem. Thank you!

To be clear, I'll display the total error message below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bobo/PycharmProjects/Assignment2.1/Main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode
  File "C:\Users\Bobo\PycharmProjects\Assignment2.1\venv\lib\site-packages\plotly\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from plotly import (plotly, dashboard_objs, graph_objs, grid_objs, tools,
  File "C:\Users\Bobo\PycharmProjects\Assignment2.1\venv\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . plotly import (
  File "C:\Users\Bobo\PycharmProjects\Assignment2.1\venv\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py", line 32, in <module>
    from _plotly_utils.basevalidators import CompoundValidator, is_array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_plotly_utils'
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have to install it with :**

```
Settings -->Project --> Project Interpreter --> on the plus right site--> search for your module and download it!
```

**and change the file name, don't use "plotly" as file name :)**

Comment: I have already installed plotly in the Project Interpreter in this way, and the file name is Main.py. But this error occured after my installation (When I go back to the interpreter now it still tells me that plotly is installed). That's the reason why I'm so confused...

Comment: Try to reinstall it